# NodeJS Web Sockets and Scalability

Tags: ios, node.js, sockets, web, websocket

I'm trying to figure out how to make a nodejs web socket scalable for production.

I'm programming a hybrid app for iOS.  All of the devices that have that app for an account gets updates via the server. I was trying to implement this with Ratchet for PHP but NodeJS seemed easier to use and maintain web sockets with. I was able to create a normal socket for this, but now my issue is scale-ability.

So far this is what I have used for scalability:

- ClusterWS - for multi threaded web sockets

This is about the only rock solid thing i have used to achieve  what i want, but i need to have multiple socket servers all connected to 1 "proxy" that can be access by all devices.

Comment: What is your specific question?  You don't seem to actually ask a question.  Please describe a problem.  Describe how you attempted to solve it and what didn't work.  Describe what you would like us to help you with.  I can't tell if this an implementation question with ClusterWS?  A question seeking a different library?  An architectural advice question?  A network infrastructure question involving proxies?  And, you don't give us any idea what scale you're trying to reach in terms of devices and packets per device per some timer period?

Comment: I need some direction on how to scale my socket server based on NodeJS. I'm kind of at a loss. I know it's vague but that's all i really have.  All tutorials online seem to be about making a simple chat room and that's about it, no scaling involved.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain exactly what you want us to help you with.  It appears you may be new here on stackoverflow.  Questions are held to a high standard here which is part of what makes the site more useful than many other question/answer sites.  You should ask a clear question that covers the things I mentioned in my previous comment.  You can use the "edit" link below your question to fix it up.  This may also help [How to ask a good question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  I will try to help when you've fixed your question.

Comment: Also, what is a "hybrid app for IOS"?

Comment: Hybrid app is an app written using something like Cordova

Comment: Please edit your question to add the things I asked about in my first comment here.  If you aren't going to clarify your question, then people will start voting to close it as unclear.  I repeat, stackoverflow requires good, clear questions that are on-topic.  You have an appropriate topic to ask about, but you need to edit your question to be clear.